# Chance level accuracy for clearly separable data

Tags: matlab, optimization, machine-learning, svm

I have written what I believe to be quite a simple SVM-classifier [SVM = Support Vector Machine]. "Testing" it with normally distributed data with different parameters, the classifier is returning me a 50% accuracy. What is wrong?

Here is the code, the results should be reproducible:

```
features1 = normrnd(1,5,[100,5]);
features2 = normrnd(50,5,[100,5]);
features = [features1;features2];
labels = [zeros(100,1);ones(100,1)];

%% SVM-Classification
nrFolds = 10; %number of folds of crossvalidation
kernel = 'linear'; % 'linear', 'rbf' or 'polynomial'
C = 1; % C is the 'boxconstraint' parameter. 

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds);


for i = 1:nrFolds                            % iterate through each fold
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                % indices test instances
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     % indices training instances

    % train the SVM
    cl = fitcsvm(features(trainIdx,:), labels(trainIdx),'KernelFunction',kernel,'Standardize',true,...
    'BoxConstraint',C,'ClassNames',[0,1]);

    [label,scores] =  predict(cl, features(testIdx,:));
    eq = sum(labels(testIdx));
    accuracy(i) = eq/numel(labels(testIdx));

end

crossValAcc = mean(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not computing the accuracy correctly.  You need to determine how many predictions match the original data.  You are simply summing up the total number of 1s in the test set, not the actual number of correct predictions.

Therefore you must change your `eq` statement to this:

```
eq = sum(labels(testIdx) == label);
```

Recall that `labels(testIdx)` extracts the true label from your test set and `label` is the predicted results from your SVM model.  This correctly generates a vector of `0/1` where `0` means that the prediction does not match the actual label from the test set and `1` means that they agree.  Summing over each time they agree, or each time the vector is `1` is the way to compute the accuracy.

Comment: yes total bug, realized it just now! question: is else the overall logic correct? I guess when I am not optimizing for hyperparameters (as here) then this validation-accuracy is equal to the accuracy of my classifier on a new testset?

Comment: @Pegah Indeed your logic is perfectly fine.  Also when you aren't optimizing the hyperparameters in this case, if the feature space is completely linearly separable, then your cross-validation accuracy at each fold should match meaning that the average should match the actual accuracy.  You've artificially made your dataset with the means being very different from one another to ensure that there is no overlap between the two distributions of data so this should definitely give you the same cross-validation at each fold.